# jquery toggle play/stop icon background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hyperlink

I have an unordered list of some video links with play icon as background in front of the links. When user clicks on a link, the video will play on a player on the left hand side of the links. When a user clicks a link, the video starts playing as well as the background icon changes to 'stop icon'. if the user clicks on another link, that link should now have stop icon as its background while the previous link's background should revert back to play icon as it is currently not playing.

```
<ul id="playlist">
        <li><a class="play" href="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" onclick="playClip(this.href); return false;">Oceans</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="play" href="http://html5videoformatconverter.com/data/images/happyfit2.mp4" onclick="playClip(this.href); return false;">Happy Fit</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="play" href="http://grochtdreis.de/fuer-jsfiddle/video/sintel_trailer-480.mp4" onclick="playClip(this.href); return false;">Sintel</a>
        </li>
</ul>
```

My CSS:

```
#playlist a.play{
    background-image: url('/_layouts/images/plplay1.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 30px;  /* width of the image plus a little extra padding */
    display: block;  /* may not need this, but I've found I do */
}

#playlist a.stop{
    background-image: url('/_layouts/images/plstop1.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 30px;  /* width of the image plus a little extra padding */
    display: block;  /* may not need this, but I've found I do */
}
```

And my JS:

```
$('#playlist li a').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('play')) {
        $(this).removeClass('play').addClass('stop');
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('stop')) {
        $(this).removeClass('stop').addClass('play');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('play');
    }
});
```

And my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2Bsm7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#playlist li a').click(function() {
        if (!($(this).hasClass('stop'))) {
            $('#playlist li a.stop').toggleClass('play stop');
        }
        $(this).toggleClass('play stop');
    }
);
```

[**Updated fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Bsm7/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
  $('#playlist li a').click(
    function() {
       $('#playlist li a').removeClass('stop').addClass('play');
       $(this).addClass('stop')
     }
   );
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2Bsm7/1/)